# Migrate CyberPanel with everything to a new CyberPanel on different VPS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alibaba-cloud, rclone, cyber-panel

I have a website running using CyberPanel on Google Cloud. I want to transfer it to Alibaba Cloud. It took a lot of effort to setup and get running the existing CyberPanel so I don't want to do it again.

Is there any way to transfer my CyberPanel to Alibaba Cloud with all configurations and websites and everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to set up a CyberPanel on Alibaba Cloud, either manually or from the Marketplace&Upgrade to the latest version.

Then use [Remote Transfer](https://cyberpanel.net/docs/3-remote-transfer/)  to migrate your accounts

If accounts load fine, then you can manually set up the rest CyberPanel settings, e.g. Cronjob, PHP extensions, firewall ..etc.